# Does MongoDB store counts for non-unique indexes?

Tags: performance, mongodb, count

Forgive the SQL syntax since I'm brand new to mongo, but if I did the equivalent of

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE indexed_field=val
```

In MongoDB, will it run in O(1) time or O(N) time where N are the number of matches? It seems the answer is O(N) based on [this commit](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/c0355ccbf0a3e242fe2db1427989bcd22311ac4c) and the fact that [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4-overview/) says it only increased performance by 20 times (whereas maintaining a count would be far greater), but I'm not sure.

Just wondering if I should cache counts for large counts. It seems like the answer is yes.

Comment: O(1) should probably be O(log(M)) where M is the number of records in the collection, but wanted to stress the perf difference.

Comment: If you can maintain the counts, you'll get the best perf by caching. O(N) could be the worst case, with O(log N) being a typical B-tree search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDBs indexes currently do not store a count per index (or collection). It makes no difference whether they are unique or non-unique indexes either. In order for MongoDB to find out how many documents there are, it needs to do an index traversal which operates in O(N)